# Какой фрэймворк или библиотеку для фронта использовать для Spring MVC приложения

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Я пишу многостраничное приложение на Spring MVC (не boot!). Скажите, пожалуйста, какие фрэймворки или библиотеки лучше всего использовать для фронта? Есть ли смысл пытаться соединить spring с react js или пилить по старинке на jQuery? Хотелось бы, конечно, попытаться поработать с reactОМ, но я никак не могу найти однозначного ответа насколько его адекватно использовать в данной ситауции и вообще понятия не имею как создать такого рода проект, в интернете вообще очень бедно по этому поводу

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/angular-vs-react-vs-vue-which-is-the-best-choice-for-2019-16ce0deb3847 По всему можно найти разнообразные готовые варианты приложений на том же Гитхабе. Да и образцов "ХеллоВорд" Ангуляр-Спринг, к примеру, в сети много.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У jQuery и React разные идеи и цели использования. jQuery это скорее набор функций для упрощения работы с JS,  в то время как React - это полноценный фреймворк для написания приложений определенной архитектуры.

Что касатется сути вопроса:
cуществует два варианта рендеринга содержимого страницы - на сервере или на стороне клиента.

Архитектура Spring MVC заточена именно под рендеринг на стороне сервера - то есть переменные страницы и их значения определяются с помощью так называемого ViewResolver. Наиболее популярными решениями являются JSP и Thymeleaf. Обычно в сочетании с ними для обеспечения простых **вспомогательных** механик используется именно jQuery или обычный JS.

Библиотеки вроде React или Angular предназначены для **разработки комплексных самодостаточных приложений** чья логика и функциональность полностью лежит на стороне клиента. Серверные данные нужны только как некий фид по ajax запросам.

Таким образом вам нужно понять - где у вас будет бизнес-логика. Если на клиенте - используйте React, от Springa вам нужны только контроллеры которые возвращают JSON например (соответственно уходим в сторону Spring Boot или если совсем молодцы то используем возможности NodeJs). 
Если на сервере, то тогда лучше попытаться реализовать всю логику на Java, а там где возникает какая либо нереализуемая на сервере интерактивность - дописывать на JS/jQuery.

Объединять же React и Spring MVC в одном проекте - это равносильно сборке трехколесного велосипеда со штырем вместо седла.

Comment: Все по делу, но на самом деле в боевых проектах на реакте жуквери все равно откуда-то но торчит(статистика)

Comment: Ну в том чтобы в react проекте использовать jquery ничего плохого нет). React - это фрейморк на базе js, jquery просто библиотека с кучей функций которую можно заимпортить в react проект чтобы не изобретать велосипеды.

Comment: еще d3 сейчас в изобилии к этому всему :)

Comment: @Tankred Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ. Скажите, как считаете, какой-нибудь интернет магазин писать с помощью spring mvc это уже не актуально и лучше использовать react или это "на вкус и цвет"?

Comment: Spring MVC хорош для корпоративных разработок, при развертывании в открытом вебе могут возникнуть проблемы с нагрузкой и масштабированием. Я бы предпочел полное JS окружение или если уж так хочется в java то не Spring MVC а Spring WebFlux (похож на MVC, но по другому идет работа с потоками).